# Programmatically add only a top border to an existing Rectangle in WPF

Tags: wpf

I am pretty sure this cannot be done, but I hope I am wrong :)

A set of rectangles exist in a wpf application that I have access to modifying via a plugin.  I cannot modify any of the existing rectangles, but can get a reference to them using FindName.

Once I have the rectangle that I want to modify, I am attempting to add a border (to only the top), by using this code

```
Rectangle selected = Core.Overlay.FindName("Rect" + rectIndex) as Rectangle
selected.Stroke = Brushes.Red;
selected.StrokeThickness = 3;
```

this of course adds a border to all 4 sides.

Is there any way to only add a top border to the existing rectangle in code?  I cannot add the rectangle to a border I create dynamically, so I am looking for another option.

Comment: Why can't you add an element on top of the `Rectangle` that covers only the top edge?

Comment: You could apply `StrokeDashArray` but would be tricky to get it to look exactly right per instance. Would be much easier obviously if you could just flip them to `Border` controls.

Comment: Fill is a brush. Use fill of the rectangles. You can make it a lineargradientbrush with a hard cut off and the gradient running vertically. You could use a converter to calculate the gradientstop proportion or go with a small number like say 0.02. I think you'd want 4 stops. Your line  colour at 0, same at 0.02. Fill at o.o2 and 1. That should give a hard edge rather than a gradient. Just using a border rather than a rectangle would be more straight forward though.